# How to import external 3D object in Scene3D in QML?

Tags: qt, qml

I have designed 3D object using 3D paint in window 10 and generated mesh and qml file corresponding to this 3D object using balsam.exe in Qt.

Please inform me how can I use a QML Node code  in generated QML file corresponding to 3D object in Scene3D in QML.

Code I have used to insert object file of 3D image in 3D scene is given below.

```
     Mesh{
        id: objectMesh
        source: "qrc:/AnyConv.com__3D_PrismWithDifferentColors.obj"
  }

  Transform {
          id: objectTransform
          rotationX:  0
          rotationY:  0
          rotationZ:  0
          translation: Qt.vector3d(0, 0, 0)
          scale3D: Qt.vector3d(10, 10, 10)
    }

    PhongMaterial {
        id: objectMaterial
        diffuse: "brown"
        ambient: "brown"
        specular: "brown"
        shininess: 1
    }

    Entity {
          id: objectEntity
          components: [ objectMesh, objectMaterial, objectTransform]
          //components: [ objectMesh,  objectTransform]
    }
```

But I did not get desired results (Attached as image for reference).

As my aim is to place 3D object image with original colors designed using other software  at origin of 3D coordinate.

Whereas I am getting required  3D image without any color of original image in 3D scene and that too away from origin of coordinate axis.

Please inform me if you need any other information from me.

Many thanks !!

[image]

Comment: Please provide [mcve] of your attempt to do that. Did you try [Mesh.source](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qt3d-render-mesh.html#source-prop)?

Comment: @folibis Thank you very much for your reply !!

Yes, I tried using Mesh.source and I have attached corresponding code in my main post. But I did not get desired results.


As my aim is to place 3D object image with original colors designed using other software  at origin of 3D coordinate. 

Whereas I am getting required  3D image without any color of original image in 3D scene and that too away from origin of coordinate axis. 

So can you please inform me how can I place original 3D image with original colors at the origin of 3D Scene in Qt 3D. 



Thank you very much !!

Comment: You cannot just import the object file 1:1, Qt is not some 3D editor. The Mesh it's just a shape so you have to define a Material and apply it to the mesh as well as the transform.

Comment: Ok folibis ...Thank you ...but is there any material in qt which can help me to get different color on each face of pyramid ..?